# Regex not working due to single quotes and double quotes

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have tested my regex on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aLxL0K/1).

It works perfectly however, on my terminal it does not 'sub' the json file.

I have a feeling it is due to the use of single and double quotes in my regex? So I have wrapped the entire pattern in triple quotes.

```
pattern = re.compile('''':\s\"(?:.*)\s([a-zA-Z]+(?:['-][a-zA-Z]+)*)\s(?=[A-Z]{2,3})(?:.*)\"''')
text = re.sub(pattern, '\1', open("/home/franticoreo/politics/politicians_and_parties.json").read())

with open("clean_politicans_and_parties.json", "w") as f:
    f.write(text)
```

I would expect the sub method to capture the only group and replace it in my json file.

Comment: Please do _not_ attempt to parse JSON strings using regex.  Use regex instead.  In fact, Python natively has a rather good `json` library which you may use.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen because it's inefficient?

Comment: What is your goal here?  What are you trying to extract from your JSON?

Comment: replace "Ms Julia Banks MP" with the surname "Banks"

Comment: What does "on my terminal" mean? If you mean you are doing something like `python -c 'pattern = re.compile(....'` then, yes, the interaction of shell quoting with python quoting is going to cause problems. Also, **do not use a regex** to parse JSON or HTML. Doing so is fragile and likely to break in surprising and hard to debug ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be the best idea to design regular expressions to do this task.

Here, we might want to simplify our expression to only capture the first value. I'm not quite sure about OAM, which is desired or not, I'm assuming is not. We then capture our desired family name in a capturing group using right boundaries and collect the entire value using left and right boundaries, maybe similar to:

```
: "(.+?(['A-za-z]+)\s(([A-Z]{2,3},\s)?[A-Z]{2}))"
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/Br4bCb/1)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r": \"(.+?(['A-za-z]+)\s(([A-Z]{2,3},\s)?[A-Z]{2}))\""

test_str = ("[\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Tony Abbott MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Anthony Albanese MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr John Alexander OAM, MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Dr Anne Aly MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Karen Andrews MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Kevin Andrews MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Adam Bandt MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Greens\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Ms Julia Banks MP\", \"party\": \"Independent\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Sharon Bird MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Chris Bowen MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Russell Broadbent MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Scott Buchholz MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Tony Burke MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Linda Burney MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Mark Butler MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Ms Terri Butler MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Anthony Byrne MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Dr Jim Chalmers MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Nick Champion MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Darren Chester MP\", \"party\": \"The Nationals\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Ms Lisa Chesters MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr George Christensen MP\", \"party\": \"The Nationals\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Jason Clare MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Ms Sharon Claydon MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon David Coleman MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Julie Collins MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Pat Conroy MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Mark Coulton MP\", \"party\": \"The Nationals\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Chris Crewther MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Milton Dick MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Mark Dreyfus QC, MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Damian Drum MP\", \"party\": \"The Nationals\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Peter Dutton MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Justine Elliot MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Warren Entsch MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Trevor Evans MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Jason Falinski MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Joel Fitzgibbon MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Paul Fletcher MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Ms Nicolle Flint MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Dr Mike Freelander MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Josh Frydenberg MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Andrew Gee MP\", \"party\": \"The Nationals\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Steve Georganas MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Andrew Giles MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Dr David Gillespie MP\", \"party\": \"The Nationals\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Ian Goodenough MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Patrick Gorman MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Luke Gosling OAM, MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Ross Hart MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Andrew Hastie MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Alex Hawke MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Chris Hayes MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Sarah Henderson MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Julian Hill MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Kevin Hogan MP\", \"party\": \"The Nationals\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Luke Howarth MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Greg Hunt MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Ed Husic MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Steve Irons MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Stephen Jones MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Barnaby Joyce MP\", \"party\": \"The Nationals\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Bob Katter MP\", \"party\": \"Katter's Australian Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Ms Ged Kearney MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Ms Justine Keay MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Michael Keenan MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Craig Kelly MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Dr Mike Kelly AM, MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Matt Keogh MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Peter Khalil MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Catherine King MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Ms Madeleine King MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Ms Susan Lamb MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Andrew Laming MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Michelle Landry MP\", \"party\": \"The Nationals\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Julian Leeser MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Dr Andrew Leigh MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Sussan Ley MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon David Littleproud MP\", \"party\": \"The Nationals\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mrs Nola Marino MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Richard Marles MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Ms Emma McBride MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Michael McCormack MP\", \"party\": \"The Nationals\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Dr John McVeigh MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Brian Mitchell MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Rob Mitchell MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Scott Morrison MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Ben Morton MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Shayne Neumann MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Llew O'Brien MP\", \"party\": \"The Nationals\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Ted O'Brien MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Brendan O'Connor MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Ken O'Dowd MP\", \"party\": \"The Nationals\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Kelly O'Dwyer MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Ms Clare O'Neil MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Ms Cathy O'Toole MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Ms Julie Owens MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Tony Pasin MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Graham Perrett MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Dr Kerryn Phelps AM, MP\", \"party\": \"Independent\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Keith Pitt MP\", \"party\": \"The Nationals\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Tanya Plibersek MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Christian Porter MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Melissa Price MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Christopher Pyne MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Rowan Ramsey MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Amanda Rishworth MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Stuart Robert MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Ms Michelle Rowland MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Ms Joanne Ryan MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Ms Rebekha Sharkie MP\", \"party\": \"Centre Alliance\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Bill Shorten MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Tony Smith MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Warren Snowdon MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Ms Anne Stanley MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Michael Sukkar MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Ms Meryl Swanson MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Angus Taylor MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Dan Tehan MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Ms Susan Templeman MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Matt Thistlethwaite MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Alan Tudge MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Ms Maria Vamvakinou MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Bert van Manen MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Ross Vasta MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Andrew Wallace MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Tim Watts MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mrs Lucy Wicks MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Andrew Wilkie MP\", \"party\": \"Independent\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Josh Wilson MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Rick Wilson MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Tim Wilson MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Jason Wood MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Hon Ken Wyatt AM, MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Tony Zappia MP\", \"party\": \"Australian Labor Party\"},\n"
    "{\"name\": \"Mr Trent Zimmerman MP\", \"party\": \"Liberal Party of Australia\"}\n"
    "]")

subst = ": \"\\2\""

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### Demo

```js
const regex = /: \"(.+?(['A-za-z]+)\s(([A-Z]{2,3},\s)?[A-Z]{2}))\"/gm;
const str = `[
{"name": "Hon Tony Abbott MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Hon Anthony Albanese MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Mr John Alexander OAM, MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Dr Anne Aly MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Hon Karen Andrews MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Hon Kevin Andrews MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Mr Adam Bandt MP", "party": "Australian Greens"},
{"name": "Ms Julia Banks MP", "party": "Independent"},
{"name": "Hon Sharon Bird MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Hon Chris Bowen MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Mr Russell Broadbent MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Hon Scott Buchholz MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Hon Tony Burke MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Hon Linda Burney MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Hon Mark Butler MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Ms Terri Butler MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Hon Anthony Byrne MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Dr Jim Chalmers MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Mr Nick Champion MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Hon Darren Chester MP", "party": "The Nationals"},
{"name": "Ms Lisa Chesters MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Mr George Christensen MP", "party": "The Nationals"},
{"name": "Hon Jason Clare MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Ms Sharon Claydon MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Hon David Coleman MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Hon Julie Collins MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Mr Pat Conroy MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Hon Mark Coulton MP", "party": "The Nationals"},
{"name": "Mr Chris Crewther MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Mr Milton Dick MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Hon Mark Dreyfus QC, MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Hon Damian Drum MP", "party": "The Nationals"},
{"name": "Hon Peter Dutton MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Hon Justine Elliot MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Hon Warren Entsch MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Mr Trevor Evans MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Mr Jason Falinski MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Hon Joel Fitzgibbon MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Hon Paul Fletcher MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Ms Nicolle Flint MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Dr Mike Freelander MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Hon Josh Frydenberg MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Hon Andrew Gee MP", "party": "The Nationals"},
{"name": "Mr Steve Georganas MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Mr Andrew Giles MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Hon Dr David Gillespie MP", "party": "The Nationals"},
{"name": "Mr Ian Goodenough MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Mr Patrick Gorman MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Mr Luke Gosling OAM, MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Mr Ross Hart MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Mr Andrew Hastie MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Hon Alex Hawke MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Mr Chris Hayes MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Hon Sarah Henderson MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Mr Julian Hill MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Mr Kevin Hogan MP", "party": "The Nationals"},
{"name": "Mr Luke Howarth MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Hon Greg Hunt MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Hon Ed Husic MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Hon Steve Irons MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Mr Stephen Jones MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Hon Barnaby Joyce MP", "party": "The Nationals"},
{"name": "Hon Bob Katter MP", "party": "Katter's Australian Party"},
{"name": "Ms Ged Kearney MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Ms Justine Keay MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Hon Michael Keenan MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Mr Craig Kelly MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Hon Dr Mike Kelly AM, MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Mr Matt Keogh MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Mr Peter Khalil MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Hon Catherine King MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Ms Madeleine King MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Ms Susan Lamb MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Mr Andrew Laming MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Hon Michelle Landry MP", "party": "The Nationals"},
{"name": "Mr Julian Leeser MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Hon Dr Andrew Leigh MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Hon Sussan Ley MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Hon David Littleproud MP", "party": "The Nationals"},
{"name": "Mrs Nola Marino MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Hon Richard Marles MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Ms Emma McBride MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Hon Michael McCormack MP", "party": "The Nationals"},
{"name": "Hon Dr John McVeigh MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Mr Brian Mitchell MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Mr Rob Mitchell MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Hon Scott Morrison MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Mr Ben Morton MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Hon Shayne Neumann MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Mr Llew O'Brien MP", "party": "The Nationals"},
{"name": "Mr Ted O'Brien MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Hon Brendan O'Connor MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Mr Ken O'Dowd MP", "party": "The Nationals"},
{"name": "Hon Kelly O'Dwyer MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Ms Clare O'Neil MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Ms Cathy O'Toole MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Ms Julie Owens MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Mr Tony Pasin MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Mr Graham Perrett MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Dr Kerryn Phelps AM, MP", "party": "Independent"},
{"name": "Hon Keith Pitt MP", "party": "The Nationals"},
{"name": "Hon Tanya Plibersek MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Hon Christian Porter MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Hon Melissa Price MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Hon Christopher Pyne MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Mr Rowan Ramsey MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Hon Amanda Rishworth MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Hon Stuart Robert MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Ms Michelle Rowland MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Ms Joanne Ryan MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Ms Rebekha Sharkie MP", "party": "Centre Alliance"},
{"name": "Hon Bill Shorten MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Hon Tony Smith MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Hon Warren Snowdon MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Ms Anne Stanley MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Hon Michael Sukkar MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Ms Meryl Swanson MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Hon Angus Taylor MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Hon Dan Tehan MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Ms Susan Templeman MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Hon Matt Thistlethwaite MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Hon Alan Tudge MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Ms Maria Vamvakinou MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Mr Bert van Manen MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Mr Ross Vasta MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Mr Andrew Wallace MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Mr Tim Watts MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Mrs Lucy Wicks MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Mr Andrew Wilkie MP", "party": "Independent"},
{"name": "Mr Josh Wilson MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Mr Rick Wilson MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Mr Tim Wilson MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Mr Jason Wood MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Hon Ken Wyatt AM, MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"},
{"name": "Mr Tony Zappia MP", "party": "Australian Labor Party"},
{"name": "Mr Trent Zimmerman MP", "party": "Liberal Party of Australia"}
]`;
const subst = `: "$2"`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

[image]

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Br4bCb/1).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the extensive response. What is OMP? Also I have found a regex that worked, however I did use the subst var which was really useful. Do you not recommend regex because it is too computationally expensive?